Database like Cellxgene for well-annotated atlas
I was trying to reinforce my manual annotation of scRNA-seq data through reference mapping using the well-annotated dataset and label transfer. There is a lot of atlas for human dataset, but I am working on mouse samples. The only source for mouse reference I know is https://cellxgene.cziscience.com/collections , but I cannot find a satisfied one that could match my own dataset, which is mostly immune cells from autoimmune models. I was wondering if anybody knows there are other good resources for such well-annotated reference atlas?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
